# Looping through multiple NetCDF files, rotate, crop and update their crs

Tags: r, loops, raster, netcdf

I have multiple NetCDF files that contain fire weather data. The files are rotated and also, other R packages (e.g., stars) and programs (e.g., cdo) do not recognize their crs but I can see the crs as WGS84 when I opened them with the raster package.

I'm looking into rotating the data to the common/regular lonlat structure, update the crs, crop the data to the extent of my study area, and writing out each NetCDF file (containing 365/366 layers) just as they were loaded.  Example data here: https://www.filemail.com/t/JtIAB1zC

Here's the code that I'm working with:

```
 all_nc = list.files("C:/file_path/", 
           pattern = ".nc$", recursive = F, full.names = T)
    
    for(i in seq_along(all_nc)){ 
          
        r = stack(all_nc[i])
        r2 = raster::rotate(brick(r))
        
        projectRaster(r2, crs = crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")) 
          
        r2 <- terra::crop(r2, terra::extent(-141.0069, -123.7893, 60, 69.64794))
          
          writeRaster(r, file.path('D:/path/', names(r)), 
                      force_v4 = T, overwrite=TRUE, format="CDF", compression = 7)
          
          }
```

> Error in if (filename == "") { : the condition has length > 1

I can get individual layers with all the changes that I want by tweaking the code but that's not what I'm hoping to achieve. I don't use loops often. So, I suspect that I'm screwing up the indexing somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this

```
fin <- list.files("C:/file_path/", pattern = ".nc$", full.names=TRUE)
fout <- gsub("C:/file_path/", "D:/path/", fin)

library(terra)    
e <- ext(-141.0069, -123.7893, 60, 69.64794)

for(i in seq_along(fin)){     
    r <- rast(fin[i])
    crs(r) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
    r <- rotate(r)   
    r <- crop(r, e)
    writeCDF(r, filename=fout[i], compression=7)
}
```

Instead of

```
r <- crop(r, e)
writeCDF(r, filename=fout[i], compression=7)
```

`writeCDF` is a better netCDF writer than `writeRaster`, but you could also use

```
r <- crop(r, e, filename=fout[i], gdal=c(COMPRESS="DEFLATE", ZLEVEL="7"))
## or 
r <- crop(r, e)
writeRaster(r, filename=fout[i], gdal=c(COMPRESS="DEFLATE", ZLEVEL="7"))
```

Note that you are mixing up a lot of "raster" and "terra" code. In the above I only use "terra". Also could you point to or share one of the files. I would like to find out why GDAL does not detect the crs.

Comment: Thanks as usual Robert.  I got an error message: "Error: [write] unknown option(s): compression". But it works if I remove the "compression =7" part. Here's the link to a sample of my data https://www.filemail.com/t/JtIAB1zC. Here's the original source: https://zenodo.org/record/3540928#.Y9xqw3bMJPY

Comment: Sorry, you need to use writeCDF to write good netcdf files use that option. See my updated answer.

Comment: Great. I'm curious about the difference in the netcdf files generate by writeCDF versus the generic approach given that the former takes longer, although does not generate .aux files like the generic approach.

Comment: `writeCDF` can write more complete netCDF files. A major difference is that the time units are stored in the file. It may not matter in your case, and I now show how to use `writeRaster` with compression options.